# Структура хранения чат сообщений в базе данных

Tags: mysql, оптимизация, chat

Друзья на днях возникла потребность оптимизировать сохранение чат сообщений в базе MySql.В принципе тип баз данных не важен.

Есть рабочий код chata который сохраняет сообщения в таблицу баз данных по принципу одно сообщение одна строка.Если пользователей будет 1000 -10 000 и может больше,что ожидается,то представьте себе сколько row бдeт в таблице.

Один из вариантов это заносить все сообщения в кэш (file, APC, даже в принципе можно в Redis хранить),и каждый 24 часа раз через cron заливать в основную базу в виде json строки.Так получится что один день это одна запись.

**Надо оптимизировать подход.**
Верно ли я думаю?
Можно ли улучшить этот вариант или есть более лучший.

Спасибо большое

Comment: Что за чат такой, где сообщения через день пишутся?

Comment: @ozornick Не сообщения через день пишутся.Вы неправильно представляете эту схему

Comment: @VanyaAvchyan какое у вас реальное количество пользователей и сообщений в день (не планируемое - 10000), а реальное на момент релиза?

Comment: @PashaPash а это имеет значение ?

Comment: @VanyaAvchyan - да, потому что если у вас реально будет десяток пользователей - то лучше всего хранить просто в одной таблице и начать решать проблему объемов тогда, когда она действительно возникнет. Например, в местном чате ruSO за все время (несколько лет) - всего 94 тыс сообщений.

Comment: @PashaPash Понимаете это не мой сайт.Я программист.И если от меня требуют оптимизации и говорят что так не пойдет,давай думай другое решение, то я должен его сделать.Если я приведу им ваши аргументы то останусь без работы :)

Comment: @VanyaAvchyan, если менеджеры считают, что знают о разработке больше программистов, то я бы на вашем месте задумался о смене места работы.

Comment: @Dmitriy Simushev  Спасибо, учту

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно в базе хранить только сообщения за последние сутки, а остальные кешировать в JSON на сервере и выдавать пользователям при запросе(как в личке в вконтакте, например).

Т.е. в чате при его загрузке будут видны только сообщения за последние сутки, 12 часов, 30 минут... Не важно.

А все остальные при запросе могут читаться из файла на сервере, либо отдельной таблицей для хранения данных в JSON формате.

По сути я описал тоже самое что и Вы, но немного иначе и, на мой взгляд, проще в плане реализации.

P.S. Так же ничего не мешает хранить последние, например, 200 сообщений, а остальные кешировать пачками по 200 или менее.

Comment: <<кешировать пачками по 200 или менее>> Как тогда узнать например сообщения за последнюю неделю?Это Придется раскрывать пачки и сверять время,что не есть хорошо,согласитесь.Хотя интересный подход.Спасибо

Comment: @VanyaAvchyan, да, с этим могут быть проблемы, но никто же не мешает хранить их по неделями или дням, да даже по часам можно.
Все в ваших руках.

Comment: @ Aim X Спасибо, я учту

Comment: @ Aim X  Но все таки чего то не хватает.Может подход сменить ? я даже не знаю