# Структура хранения сообщений чата в базе данных

Tags: база-данных, оптимизация, хранение-данных, чат

Собственно, вопрос навеян другим [вопросом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/548018/%D0%A1%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B0-%D1%85%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%82-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%B2-%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85).
Заключается в следующем.
Какой оптимальный способ хранения сообщений чата? Может быть лучше их сохранять вообще просто в файл (ведь обращение к старым практически исключено, а вычитка последних может идти и из оперативной памяти)? Или может быть лучше (как в упомянутом [вопросе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/548018/%D0%A1%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B0-%D1%85%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%82-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%B2-%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85)) рассматривать хранение сообщений в базе в виде JSON-строк за определенный период времени? А может все-таки лучше их хранить в базе в виде "одно сообщение - одна строка" и при этом все данные расположены по полям? Какие еще есть варианты? Какие у этих вариантов (и других) плюсы и минусы?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галочка напротив выбранного ответа)

Comment: @Mihanik71 Несомненно, так и поступлю. Но не ранее, чем отвечающие начнут читать вопрос и отвечать по существу вопроса.

Comment: Укажите какими средствами делается серверная часть. И какую БД вы имеете ввиду. Если реляционную - отдельная строка на сообщение, без вариантов. Если документарную или около того - то видимо JSON или как там она документ хранит. С файлами - в определенных случаях можно сделать оптимально, но объем работы на пару порядков выше.

Comment: @Mike Прочитайте вопрос. Ведь черным по белому написано: как лучше хранить сообщения чата? Может лучше вообще без базы? Причем здесь Ваши комментарии по поводу базы данных? Причем здесь непосредственно JSON, если я в вопросе написал, что это как вариант, а как другой вариант - традиционное сохранение в базе по строкам и полям. Какая разница при этом какими средствами делается серверная часть? Есть средства, которые позволят ее сделать, но не позволят использовать базу данных или файловую систему?

Comment: Очень хотелось бы уточнить у  тех, кто требует правки, как можно отредактировать простой вопрос:Какой оптимальный способ хранения сообщений чата?И да.Ну очень много ответов может быть основано сугубо на чьем-то мнении. Вот их бы и хотелось услышать. Но услышать мнения по существу вопроса, а не ответы о том, как данные из базы будут потом плохо читаться.В вопросе указано, что это чат (не мессенджер) и читаться сообщения не будут.Ответов по существу нет, несмотря на разжеванный вопрос?Как, уважаемые, господа-товарищи вы предлагаете его переформулировать?Может прочтете его внимательно для начала?

Comment: @Softinaria, без конкретных входных данных и ограничений от вас здесь будут только рассуждения в духе "можно так, а можно и эдак". А это неформат для StackOverflow. В таком духе можно провести обсуждение в [чатике](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22462/stack-overflow--).

Answer (score 1):

**Хранение в JSON данных за день/месяц/год:**

> +Легко отдавать данные за период
>
> -Отсутствует возможность поиска
>
> -Увеличение размера хранимых данных
>
> -Большой объём передаваемых данных
>
> -Усложнение системы хранения данных (сначала нужно хранить где то данные за период, потом переносить в базу)

**Хранение в файлах данных за день/месяц/год:**

> +Легко отдавать данные за период
>
> -Отсутствует возможность поиска
>
> -Увеличение размера хранимых данных
>
> -Большой объём передаваемых данных
>
> -Усложнение системы хранения данных (сначала нужно хранить где то данные за период, потом переносить в файл)

**Хранение в базе:**

> +Легко отдавать данные за период
>
> +Стандартные возможность поиска
>
> +Передаём только нужные данные
>
> -Хранятся актуальные и старые сообщения

---

В лучшую сторону ничего не изменится если Вы будете хранить сообщения в JSON.

- Места занимает столько же, а то и больше.
- Теряется возможность запросов. Нельзя будет сделать сложных запросов.
- Передавать данные сложнее. (Кто то очень активный наобщается на 10 метров и будете Вы на клиент их передавать).

Хранить в файлах историю по дням можно, но тоже не особо что то поменяет.

Вы боитесь что если у Вас будет несколько миллионов записей, то у Вас скорость запросов упадёт при обычном селекте? Это не так доступ же линейный.

А по всему остальному в чём разница — хранить в базе или в файлах? Что то что то место занимает.

Лучше чем просто в базе ещё вроде не придумали.

Comment: На счет потери возможности запросов при хранении сообщений в JSON, я бы не был так категоричен. Разве базы данных (как например, MySQL, MongoDB) не поддерживают возможность запросов к данным, сохраненным в JSON?

Comment: Вопрос (и речь в целом) идет о хранении сообщений в базе данных (или в файле). И это никак не связано с тем, что кто-то наобщается на 10 метров, которые нужно будет передать на клиент. То что он наобщается - будет передано и так и эдак и в другом формате.

Comment: Я не боюсь падения скорости при доступе. Я достаточно четко указал причину вопроса (другой вопрос другого человека). Меня интересуют плюсы и минусы разных подходов.

Comment: Читаем вопрос и делаем выводы... Это чат, а не мессенджер. Нет никакой необходимости осуществлять поиск по сохранненным данным и отдавать их. И никакой роли размер этих данных не играет. Весь же Ваш ответ (плюсы/минусы) построен исключительно на поиске и возврате старых данных.

Answer (score -1):

1. Если вы будете хранить сообщения в  файлах, вам придется решить несколько вопросов:

   - один файл или много.
   - если один файл, как обеспечить многопоточную запись.
   - как индексировать записи
   - если много файлов - как быть с файловой системой? сколько этих файлов, сколько места на жестком диске потеряется? Как индексировать записи, как обеспечить многопоточную запись в кучу файлов?

если вы будете хранить сообщения в файлах, то вы не будете этого делать. Ну или напишете, фактически, через год-два,  свою собственную базу данных. Скорее всего очень медленную и плохую. Если ваш стартапик при этом не лопнет - задача решена!

2. Если хранить сообщения в SQL БД, упаковывая все поля в JSON, вы изобретете знаменитый (вру) *двойной велосипед*, вы будете хранить неструктурированные данные в RDBMS. Все будет очень медленно и плохо. Практически единственным способом поиска для вас будет оператор LIKE, индексы в данном случае не имеют смысла, все будет ОЧЕНЬ, ОЧЕНЬ плохо.
3. Выбор между NoSQL или SQL делайте сами, но, в любом случае и те и другие хранят поля документа/таблицы раздельно.
4. Очень советую почитать немножко про базы данных в целом.

P.S. представьте себе данные типа

```
from:покемон;vorobusheq;message:ei ti;
```

превратим это в json-строку:

```
{"from":"покемон","to":"vorobusheq","message":"ei ti"}
```

вторая строчка длиннее. В базе данных это будет выглядеть скорее так:
`покемон,vorobusheq,ei ti` 
c индексом на смещения в файлах базы данных

Comment: Если он будет хранить Json в Mongo то никаких проблем у него не будет!

Comment: @strangeqargo а теперь Вы себе представьте, что я задавал вопрос о плюсах и минусах перечисленных мною способах, а также о том, какие еще могут быть варианты. И представьте, что никто не собирался сохранять каждое отдельное сообщение в файл. А если хранить даже по дням, то это всего лишь 365 файлов за год. Это какую-то нагрузку для ФС ОСи представляет?

Comment: @strangeqargo А причем здесь вообще многопоточная запись? Прием сообщений от разных клиентов идет не в разные потоки - это просто глупо иметь на каждого клиента отдельный поток. Поэтому и о многопоточной записи глупо было даже задумываться. А про место на диске это вообще просто смешно... Или Вы думаете, что база данных хранит данные в другом месте?

Comment: @strangeqargo А еще не понятно, какой же я велосипед изобрету, сохраняя JSON в базе данных? Удивлю Вас... MySQL работает с JSON. MongoDB работает с JSON. Где же неструктурированные данные? Почему только LIKE? Что будет очень , очень плохо?  Может быть прочитать про базы данных ст_О_ит Вашей башке? Хоть немножко... И еще книжку про этику почитайте.

Comment: @Softinaria Если у вас скажем web приложение - то запись всегда многопоточная, ибо web сервер запустит в параллель несколько процессов и в какой момент какому из них надо будет писать большой вопрос. (вы даже не указали в вопросе какого рода приложение делаете). MySQL может работать в JSON, только вот индексы при этом использовать не может и будет полный перебор таблицы при любом поиске. При старте чата часто показывают скажем 10 сообщений, но вы не знаете за какой они период. СУБД с нормально построенным индексом мгновенно найдет 10 последних записей (при хранении построчно)

Comment: @Mike Читаем вопрос: как лучше хранить сообщения, а не записывать их в несколько потоков. Читаем еще раз вопрос: обращение к старым сообщениям исключено, а небольшое количество из ОЗУ подчитается. При чем здесь переборы и индексы?

Comment: @ДмитрийГвоздь если он будет запихивать именно строчки джейсона в монго, проблемы будут.

Comment: mysql выводит json, но хранит-то он его не строчками. Олсо, про башку уберу, кек.

Comment: @strangeqargo  Еще и еще раз... Вопрос о том, как лучше хранить сообщения чата. Какие есть варианты и их плюсы/минусы. Вопрос не про JSON и его хранение в базе данных. С какого перепугу вы прицепилилсь к JSON или к базам данных? Складывается впечатление, что отвечающие не читают вопрос и в принципе не знают ничего, кроме JSON и баз данных - увидели знакомые слова и понеслась звезда по кочкам.

Comment: в бд. одно сообщение - одна строка. разнесенная по полям. на нужных полях - индексы. альтернатив нет %)