# Что эффекивней разделение таблиц или их индексация?

Tags: sql, оптимизация

Скажем есть таблица из двух полей `time` и `data`. Обращение к ней происходит по какому то периоду времени, то есть по сути частые обращение происходят только к определенной части таблицы. Для оптимизации скорости выполнения можно пойти двумя путями:

1. создавать отдельную таблицу для каждого периода
2. проиндексировать таблицу по периоду

Возникает вопрос какой способ эффективней? Если есть другие способы ускорения то рад буду вас выслушать.

Comment: Индексация даже не обсуждается - в любом случае. Отдельные таблицы - несерьёзно... но можно подумать о партиционировании по дате.

Comment: @Akina а что такое партиционирование? я понимаю что это разбивка по времени но по какому принципу? проще говоря что я для этого должен сделать?

Comment: Однозначно тоже нельзя говорить.Эти два материала помогут вам более точнее понять. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/548018/%D0%A1%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B0-%D1%85%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%82-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%B2-%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85  i https://habrahabr.ru/post/133781/

Comment: @Akina существуют такие запросы, скорости выполнения которых отнюдь не помогают индексы — например, в случае, когда по индексу выбирается больше чем около 1/10 всех записей в таблице, оптимизатор предпочтет FTS (Full Table Scan) вместо использования индекса, поскольку последовательное чтение с диска происходит быстрее, чем читать из разных частей диска (передвижение головки по диску — seek — это “дорогая” операция)

Comment: @VanyaAvchyan Это верно, бывает и такое. Но у товарища явно файл лога или нечто подобное - т.е. длинная история и узкие временнЫе срезы. Как итог - индекс работает в полную силу. К тому же я не предлагаю строить индекс по какому-нибудь сильно-огрубляющему выражению, а по полю даты у индексов селективность всегда высокая. Что же до апелляции к физике накопителя, то она бессмысленна - как с учётом работы кэшей (а их минимум 3 уровня), так и с учётом того, что данные крайне редко бывают нефрагментированными.

Comment: @Akina Да для товарища выбор индексов это правильный вариант.Да в 90 % случаев еменно они и нужны.Надеяться на кэширование при динамических изменений таблицы по моему тоже не стоит.

Comment: @perfect, партиционирование - это механизм некоторых СУБД, позволяющий разделить таблицу на несколько, по значению индексируемого поля. Для пользователя это выглядит как одна таблица, но работа происходит заметно быстрее.

Comment: @ГерманБорисов спасибо, а ссылку на postgre не дадите по этому механизму

Comment: @perfect, конкретно с PostgreSQL я не знаком, но гугл по запросу "postgresql секционирование таблиц" выдает много инфы на русском.

Comment: @ГерманБорисов спасибо. значит на самом деле секционирование а не партиционирование. да это более корректное выражение.

Answer (score 1):

Зависит от конкретной СУБД и объема данных.

Если есть механизм автоматической кластеризации или партиционирования, то лучше воспользоваться им.

Если нет, то стоит провести эксперимент.

Но точно не стоит делать отдельную таблицу на каждый период - это сильно усложняет логику. Можно сделать одну таблицу на основной период и одну на все остальные.

Comment: *точно не стоит делать отдельную таблицу на каждый период - это сильно усложняет логику* Не всегда. Если это локальное приложение частного уровня, а данные хранятся на MyISAM, то частные таблицы плюс MERGE-надтаблица может быть не самым плохим решением.

Comment: MERGE в MyISAM я бы отнес к (полу)автоматической кластеризации средствами СУБД, что, в общем случае, предпочтительнее любого велосипеда с ручной кластеризацией.